# Substring based on 2 string identifiers in a long string

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a simple requirement where i have a Dataframe with only one string field with a very large string value. I just want to chop it down to select desired information.

The String field in my dataframe contains below value-

```
Table(tableName:partition_chk, dbName:stage, owner:hive, createTime:1559243466, lastAccessTime:0, retention:0, sd:StorageDescriptor(cols:[FieldSchema(name:id, type:string, comment:null), FieldSchema(name:name, type:string, comment:null), FieldSchema(name:dw_date, type:string, comment:null)], location:hdfs://share/dev/stage/partition_chk, inputFormat:org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TextInputFormat, outputFormat:org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveIgnoreKeyTextOutputFormat, compressed:false, numBuckets:-1, serdeInfo:SerDeInfo(name:null, serializationLib:org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.lazy.LazySimpleSerDe, parameters:{line.delim=, field.delim=,, serialization.format=,}), bucketCols:[], sortCols:[], parameters:{}, skewedInfo:SkewedInfo(skewedColNames:[], skewedColValues:[], skewedColValueLocationMaps:{}), storedAsSubDirectories:false), partitionKeys:[FieldSchema(name:dw_date, type:string, comment:null)], parameters:{EXTERNAL=TRUE, transient_lastDdlTime=1559243466}, viewOriginalText:null, viewExpandedText:null, tableType:EXTERNAL_TABLE)
```

All i want from this value is the base location of partitions which is- "hdfs://share/dev/stage/partition_chk"

Please note i just want this above quoted string (without "location:" prefix). Any ideas what substing operations in pyspark might do the trick.

Thanks!

Sid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways to do this, but a regex is the most straight forward one in my opinion. In pyspark you need the [regexp_extract](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.1/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.regexp_extract) function to apply a regex and extract the match groups. The regex is the next important thing for you. The following regex:

`location:([a-zA-Z:\/\/_]*)`

matches all characters of the following:

- lower case characters
- upper case characters
- :
- /
- _

after the encounter of `location:`. Of course you could also use something like `location:([^,]*)`,  which matches everything after `location:` until the first comma, but this really depends on the possible matches. Below is an example:

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

l = [
(  "Table(tableName:partition_chk, dbName:stage, owner:hive, createTime:1559243466, lastAccessTime:0, retention:0, sd:StorageDescriptor(cols:[FieldSchema(name:id, type:string, comment:null), FieldSchema(name:name, type:string, comment:null), FieldSchema(name:dw_date, type:string, comment:null)], location:hdfs://share/dev/stage/partition_chk, inputFormat:org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TextInputFormat, outputFormat:org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveIgnoreKeyTextOutputFormat, compressed:false, numBuckets:-1, serdeInfo:SerDeInfo(name:null, serializationLib:org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.lazy.LazySimpleSerDe, parameters:{line.delim=, field.delim=,, serialization.format=,}), bucketCols:[], sortCols:[], parameters:{}, skewedInfo:SkewedInfo(skewedColNames:[], skewedColValues:[], skewedColValueLocationMaps:{}), storedAsSubDirectories:false), partitionKeys:[FieldSchema(name:dw_date, type:string, comment:null)], parameters:{EXTERNAL=TRUE, transient_lastDdlTime=1559243466}, viewOriginalText:null, viewExpandedText:null, tableType:EXTERNAL_TABLE)"  , )
]

columns = ['hugeString']

df = spark.createDataFrame(l, columns)

#collect() turns the dataframe into a python list of Rows
#I don't know if you need this or not
#In case you want to extract it into a new column, use withColumn instead of select
df.select(F.regexp_extract('hugeString', "location:([a-zA-Z:\/_]*)", 1).alias('match')).collect()[0]['match']
```

Output:

```
hdfs://share/dev/stage/partition_chk
```

Comment: Thank you so much...exactly what i was looking for!